# Android CardView: Why the corners are not round?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

SOLVED!

Solution: 
remove the background color from the layout and set it on the card view itself as

`app:cardBackgroundColor=" # the color you want"`

and make sure you have the following dependency

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

Those should do the job.

Update! --> Added extra information

I have the following activity in which I try to make 3 card views containing information.
And I want to make the card views to have rounded corners.

I use the `app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"` but it's not showing any result, the corners still do not look round.

Any idea where is my mistake and what I need to do in order to have them rounded?
Is it because of the layout inside the CardView?

**Thank you!**

Below you can see the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.ViewRecipe"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/mainBackgroundColorRM">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Spaghette"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="32sp" />


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp">

            <!-- Here add the Contact Details-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/buttonColorRM"
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">
                <!-- Here add the time value -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_duration_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="10 minute"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Here add the portii value -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_servings_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_duration_value"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="@string/Servings_VALUE_demo"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Duration is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_duration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/text_duration_ViewRecipe"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text_view_duration_value"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Time is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_portii"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_duration"
                    android:text="@string/text_servings_ViewRecipe"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Ingredients -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <!-- Here add the Contact Details-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:background="@color/buttonColorRM">

                <!-- Duration is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_ingredients"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="  Incrediente:"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/list_icon">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Time is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_ingredients_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_ingredients"
                    android:text="Incredient 1, incredient 2, altul mai unul si ai unul"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#000000">

                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Recipe -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <!-- Recipe description is here-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:background="@color/buttonColorRM">

                <!-- Duration is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_recipe"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/text_view_descriere_ViewRecipe"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/description_icon">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Time is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_recipe_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_recipe"
                    android:text="@string/demo_reteta"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Also here it is the Gradle Module App file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ciucurdaniel.romania.retetelemele"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    //AD MOB
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'

    //CardView
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Remove this line: app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"

Comment: @Jason I removed it, but still no rounded corners

Comment: On which API are you running the app?

Comment: Hi, @GabrieleMariotti I updated the description :)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti API Level 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `CardView` are round corner but not displayed rounded because you set the background of the inner layout. just move that background inner layout to `CardView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.ViewRecipe"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/mainBackgroundColorRM">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Spaghette"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="32sp" />


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonColorRM"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp">

            <!-- Here add the Contact Details-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">
                <!-- Here add the time value -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_duration_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="10 minute"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Here add the portii value -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_servings_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_duration_value"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="@string/Servings_VALUE_demo"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Duration is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_duration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/text_duration_ViewRecipe"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text_view_duration_value"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Time is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_portii"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_duration"
                    android:text="@string/text_servings_ViewRecipe"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Ingredients -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonColorRM"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <!-- Here add the Contact Details-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                >

                <!-- Duration is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_ingredients"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="  Incrediente:"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/list_icon">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Time is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_ingredients_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_ingredients"
                    android:text="Incredient 1, incredient 2, altul mai unul si ai unul"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#000000">

                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Recipe -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonColorRM"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <!-- Recipe description is here-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                >

                <!-- Duration is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_recipe"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/text_view_descriere_ViewRecipe"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/description_icon">
                </TextView>

                <!-- Time is here-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_recipe_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_recipe"
                    android:text="@string/demo_reteta"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hello @Dinesh! Thanks for the answer! I changed according to your solution and it still doesn't show them as round. Any further ideas?

Comment: Also yes, your solution was right if I put the background color in the layout then the card will not be ("seen") rounded. Your solution works, plus the dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally did it while doing another thing. I wanted to change my EditTexts to have floating labels. And when I added the following dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

the corners of the CardViews also became round.

Also important to mention that what @Dinesh said should be done also.
You need to set background color on the card view and not on its inner layout, otherwise, it will "cover" it's corners and you will not see them as round corners.

Answer (score 0):

**check in manifest if there is this field remove it**
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).